What are wrapped tokens, and how do they utilize the ERC-20 standard?
The question addresses how wrapped tokens convert non-Ethereum assets into ERC-20 compliant tokens, allowing them to be used on the Ethereum network.

Wrapped tokens are representation of outside coins on said blockchain.
Will explain with example
I have 1 BTC but i cannot use it on ethereum blockchain to do so i will need 1:1 representation of BTC on ehtereum blockchain, so i will go to an organization that can help me with that.
So this organization has smart contract setup which can mint and burn tokens.
I give them my btc, they mint a WBTC (Wrapped BTC) on ETH blockchain, give me the wrapped token. now i can use it as a ethereum token.
when i am done or need my native BTC back i go to back to the organization give them WBTC, they burn it and give me corresponding amount of native BTC

Thank you for the clear explanation of wrapped tokens and their use of the ERC-20 standard! Your example really helped clarify how the process works.
